# nohup with scripy asking for parameter

Tags: linux, nohup

I am trying to use the nohup command.

```
# nohup python3.6 script.py
```

Problem the script ask for a parameter at start :

```
# How many times would like to loop ? :*
```

and with nohup, i do not see the questions on script start.

Can you help me please ?

Yoki

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found !!!
Sorry !!

( echo 10 | nohup python3.6 script.py )